# How to prove that $F(x,y)=(f(x)h(y),g(y))$ is a diffeomorphism?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $F:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ be given by $F(x,y)=(f(x)h(y),g(y))$, where $h:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a diferentiable function and $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ are diffeomorphisms.

> **Definition:** a *diffeomorphism* is a bijective differentiable mapping whose inverse is also differentiable.

The problem is to show that the following sentences are equivalent.

(a) $F$ is a diffeomorphism.
(b) $0\notin h(\mathbb{R})$.

If $f,g,h$ are $C^1$ functions, then $F$ is a $C^1$ function and thus we can use the following fact.

> **Theorem:** Let $U\subset\mathbb{R}^m$ be an open set and $F:U\to\mathbb{R}^m$ a $C^1$ function. Then, $F$ is a local diffeomorphism if, and only if, $\det J_F(x)\neq 0$ for all $x\in U$.

In that case, I think the solution can be done as below.

- (a) $\Rightarrow$ (b)

Since $F$ is a diffeomorphism, it's a local diffeomorphism. Since $F$ is $C^1$, it follows from theorem above that $\det J_F(x,y)\neq 0$ for all $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$. But 
$$\det J_F(x,y)\neq 0\quad\Rightarrow\quad h(y)f'(x)g'(y)\neq0\quad\Rightarrow\quad h(y)\neq 0$$
so that $h(y)\neq 0$ for all $y\in\mathbb{R}$, that is, $0\notin h(\mathbb{R})$.

- (b) $\Rightarrow$ (a)

Since $f,g$ are diffeomorphisms, $f'(x)g'(y)\neq 0$ for all $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$. Since $0\notin h(\mathbb{R}^2)$, it follows that
$\det J_F(x,y)=h(y)f'(x)g'(y)\neq0$ for all $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$. As $F$ is $C^1$, we conclude from theorem above that $F$ is a local diffeomorphism. But we can prove that $F$ is bijective (because $f,g$ are bijective). So, $F$ is indeed a diffeomorphism.

**However, the hypothesis $f,g,h\in C^1$ is not a part of the exercise. So, how can we solve it without that hypothesis?**

Thanks.

Comment: For $(a)\implies (b)$, show $\lnot(b)\implies \lnot(a)$, and for $(b)\implies (a)$, you can explicitly write down the inverse and show it is differentiable.

Comment: @DanielFischer $0\in h(\mathbb{R})\Rightarrow F$ is not injective, and $$F^{-1}(x,y)=\left(f^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{h\left(g^{-1}(y)\right)}\right),g^{-1}(y)\right)$$
right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Daniel Fischer said, the  inverse map can be explicitly written (which you did correctly):
$$F^{-1}(x,y)=\left(f^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{h\left(g^{-1}(y)\right)}\right),g^{-1}(‌​y)\right)$$
Here $f^{-1}$, $g^{-1}$, and $h$ are differentiable by assumption.